# Spool command breaking header

Tags: spool

I've got a problem when spooling into a csv from sqlplus
Here is my script:

```
    set heading on;
    set colsep ',';
    set pause off;
    set pages 0;
    set pagesize 50000;
    set feedback off;
    set term off;
    set echo off;
    set verify off;
    set linesize 20000;
    set trimspool on;

    SELECT
        "Van Name",
        "Date",
        "Shift_ID",
        "Shift",
        "Departure Weight",
        "Reload",
        "Maximum Capacity (Weight)",
        "Planned Distance(KM)",
        "Shift Start Time",
        "Departure Time",
        "Depart Last Stop" from
```

Out put of above spool is not properly resulting into csv. facing below issues.

1. Example: "Shift" in my select statement (4columns) is just coming
   up as 'Shi' but other which has long description is coming file
2. Resulting empty row at 1st and as expected 2nd row header
3. 3rd, I am getting underline as ---------

Could some one suggest how to fix above 3 points greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some concrete example input and output and the expected output?

Comment: Hi, i was not able to attach screen shot as dont have option. Sample input query i have mentioned in my question and when i run that query from script, its extracting in below format.

1. First column is coming empty - which not supposed to empty
2. Second column is fine coming with header but few rows is not completely extracted. i.e., "Shift" row is coming as "Shi". its not size limit as i could see other rows which are big in size are extracting correctly.
3. Third column is coming with under line "--------"

Comment: So i dont want 1st(Blank) and 2nd(---) Columns. Rows should arrear completely as example "Shift"